# Nav and Footer issues with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to implement, what seems to be a simple enough layout, but I have having strange issues with my CSS.

There are 3 parts to what I really require:

1) I would like a sticky navigation bar that is always visible as the user scrolls (like twitter.com)

2) For my footer I would like it to always flush to the bottom of the page no matter what the height of the content is. (note: **not** a sticky footer, just always flushed to the bottom of the page, or below the content is there is a lot of content).

3) Lastly, and this is where I am really stuck. I would like for my content area (in-between the header/footer) to be 100% of the visible area, unless there is more content in which case it scrolls like normal.

As an example, my home page is quote long, so that is not an issue, but the other content pages are smaller but require certain repeated background images and such which should fill the whole screen, but always seem to only fill their actual space.

**EDIT** (Including the HTML and CSS)

I'm using AngularJS (hence the ng-view).

The project is **HUGE** and I have been trying to fix up the CSS so it can be posted:

```
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#/area1">LINK 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/area2">LINK 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="logoLink" href="#/">
                        <img class="headerLogo" src="static/img/logo.png" >
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid full-height">
            <div class="row-fluid full-height">
                <div class="span12 full-height" ng-view>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="footer">
        Footer goes here
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 142px;
}

.footer {
    background: #1D1D1B;
    color: white;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 81px;
}

.full-height {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: 4 gold, 34 silver, 99 bronze and question without any relevant code or a demo

Comment: Set the minimum height of the `<html>` and `<body>` tag to `100%`. 

CSS:

    html{
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    body{
      min-height: 100%;
    }

Comment: @Mr.Alien sorry, just updated, this code base is a mess and I am trying to clean it up so I can post it, it has lots of customer sensitive info

Comment: @KevinPaladin thanks for the tip, does seem to work quite right, the bootstrap css class of `container-fluid` never seems to fill the space

Comment: question closed?!?!? come on! I was in the middle of an edit!

Comment: @Mark: Don't forget that being "closed" means "It's on hold until it can be edited and improved". It has 3 reopen votes now, and I've posted a [tag:rov-pls] request. It should be reopened shortly :)

Comment: did you try giving height 100% to the successive `div`s too?

Comment: That seems to work, but the footer is then pushed down out of view at all times!?! I will try to update the code in question

Comment: Just added new update to the HTML and CSS, it seems that the `height: auto !important;` is the problem, but if I remove it my footer doesnt stay at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag `<body>` twice on your html, by the way.

Try this :

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
      }

.wrapper {
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto -60px;
}

.push, .footer {
   height: 60px;
}
.footer {
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.footer {
   margin-left: -20px;
   margin-right: -20px;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   }
}

.wrapper > .container-fluid {
   padding-top: 60px;
}
.footer p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

<kbd>**[demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/nhbarkii)**</kbd>